# Frame morphisms.

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, lattice-orders, generalized-topology

The following is a well known fact:

> A frame morphism $\Phi : B \to A$, considered as a map of posets has a right adjoint $\Psi : A  \to B$.

My question is, under which hypotesis $\Phi \Psi \Phi = \Phi $ or $\Psi \Phi \Psi = \Psi$? I am asking because I do believe this might happen very often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is: it's always true.

Observe that since you are dealing with adjunctions between posets you have the units 
$$\eta_X \colon X {\longrightarrow} \Psi\Phi(X)$$
and counits 
$$\epsilon_Y \colon \Phi\Psi(Y){\longrightarrow} Y$$
applying to them the monotone mappings (functors) $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ respectively you get 
$$\Phi(\eta_X) \colon \Phi(X) \to \Phi\Psi\Phi(X)$$
and 
$$\Psi(\epsilon_Y) \colon\Psi\Phi\Psi(Y) \to \Psi(Y)$$
which testify that $\Phi(X) \leq \Phi\Psi\Phi(X)$ and $\Psi\Phi\Psi(Y)\leq\Psi(Y)$ for each $X \in B$ and $Y \in A$.

On the other hand we have also the morphisms 
$$\eta_{\Psi(Y)}\colon \Psi(Y) \to \Psi\Phi\Psi(Y)$$
and 
$$\epsilon_{\Phi(X)} \Phi\Psi\Phi(X) \to \Phi(X)$$
which testify that $\Psi(Y) \leq \Psi\Phi\Psi(Y)$ and $\Phi\Psi\Phi(X)\leq \Phi(X)$.

By anti-symmetric property of the orders you get that $\Phi(X)=\Phi\Psi\Phi(X)$ and $\Psi(Y)=\Psi\Phi\Psi(Y)$ for every $X \in B$ and $Y \in A$.